# Run a specific version of Julia in Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia

I recently installed Julia version `0.7.0` (I need this older version). Prior to that, I had installed Julia `1.6.2`, and I can use it in Jupyter notebook. Now, through Julia command line in version `0.7.0`, I installed IJulia, and after launching the jupyter notebook through the same command line, I am not able to open notebooks in version `0.7.0`. I only see options for `1.6.2`.

How can I launch a notebook with version `0.7.0` of Julia?

**UPDATE**

Now I am able to see Julia `0.7.0` as an option when I open Jupyter notebook, but now the kernel does not connect when I want to use it for this specific version. It works fine for version `1.6.2`.

I have tried opening a notebook in two different ways:

1. From anaconda command line: The notebook launches, but the kernel does not connect. The following error keeps repeating:

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching setindex!(::Ptr{Nothing}, ::Ptr{Nothing})
Stacktrace:
 [1] start_heartbeat(::ZMQ.Socket) at C:\Users\josh\.julia\packages\IJulia\AQu2H\src\heartbeat.jl:20
 [2] init(::Array{String,1}) at C:\Users\josh\.julia\packages\IJulia\AQu2H\src\init.jl:100
 [3] top-level scope at none:0
 [4] include at .\boot.jl:317 [inlined]
 [5] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at .\loading.jl:1038
 [6] include(::Module, ::String) at .\sysimg.jl:29
 [7] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at .\client.jl:239
 [8] _start() at .\client.jl:432
in expression starting at C:\Users\josh\.julia\packages\IJulia\AQu2H\src\kernel.jl:24
```

2. From Julia command line: I get a message that says `Process Exited(1)` at the end without opening any notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
julia> using Pkg; Pkg.build("IJulia")
```

within the 0.7 REPL. This should install the Jupyter kernel for Julia 0.7 and make it available as an option.

In case that doesn't work for some reason, you can also try explicitly calling the `installkernel` function:

```
julia> installkernel("Julia 0.7")
```

Comment: Thanks! I am able to see it as an option now, but there are other errors now. I updated the question with the error message.

Comment: 1. Could you try the debugging steps mentioned here: https://julialang.github.io/IJulia.jl/stable/manual/troubleshooting/#Debugging-IJulia-problems and see if that prints any additional information? 2. Also try `Pkg.test("IJulia")` and `Pkg.test("ZMQ")` and check that everything passes.

Comment: 1. Unfortunately no additional information was printed. 
2. Both of them passed.

Comment: Seems worth opening an issue about, in that case (mentioning these results from the DEBUG and the `test`s too). It's quite possible some 0.7-incompatible change creeped in unintentionally, just because it's so rarely used.